# How to convert exponential number to normal number in qtp?

Tags: qtp, vbscript, uft, qtp-11.0

Getting some exponential value in qtp/uft while performing multiplication with huge numbers. But I want the exact decimal value of it.

E.g.:  I am getting something like 15525.22352000e25

I need the exact value of it like 15525.22352554585.......

- Numbers are examples, Not exact :)

I need it for at least 15 decimal digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Numbers in computations

Exponential representation of numbers is used for `Double` data type (15 significant digits, so called `mantissa`, and E-part, so called `exponent`).

Let's see your example `15525.22352000e25`. It is converted to `Double` because it is greater than the biggest integer data type `Long` (values from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`)

There is another data type `Currency` but it is limited by values from `-922,337,203,685,477.5808` to `922,337,203,685,477.5807` (it's about 9.2e14) so it's not enough to store you number `15525.22e25` without conversion to `Double`.

**So there is no way to store `15525.22352000e25` without loosing some accuracy**. This example needs 30 significant digits.

But as you said:

> need it for at least 15 decimal digits

`Double` data type is just what you need, it has 15 significant digits:

> Contains a double-precision, floating-point number in the range
>   -1.79769313486232E308 to -4.94065645841247E-324 for negative values; 4.94065645841247E-324 to 1.79769313486232E308 for positive values.

### Numbers in string output

If you need just to show this number without exponent part to user you can use `FormatNumber(number)` function:

```
FormatNumber(15525.22352000e25)
' Output: "155 252 235 200 000 000 000 000 000 000,00"
```